# Export Websphere 6.1 Profile with datasource configuration

Tags: resources, websphere, profile

I'm trying to export a profile from WAS 6.1 so that I can give it to other members of my team with all of the JNDI and Shared Library configurations in place. I've flowed a few IBM tutorials on this like http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21322309 (technically that is more a bug fix, but there is a similar page). I've tried to export the server using the "import" feature of the server in RAD 7. None of these options create a .car file with the resources sticking around.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,
JPD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried exporting/importing the WAS configuration using the `wsadmin` console as described in the following IBM TechNote?

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21207526

Unfortunately, the SIB configuration will be missing from the export -- I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature, but it's at least mentioned by IBM in their TechNote so you don't have to pull out your hair searching for the problem.

Comment: the actual page has been moved I think, the link works, but it says document not found

Comment: Yeah, it looks like IBM redesigned their website; I can't find that particular TechNote anymore. :(